# get all file names from serialized data

Tags: php

I have a serialized data in which there is a record of multiple images and their size . I wanted to get all files names and then replace them with my data . I have used serialize to accomplish that but i am not able to get all file names .

```
$s2mebership_details='a:5:{s:5:"width";i:200;s:6:"height";i:200;s:4:"file";s:27:"6month_project_training.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:5:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:33:"6month_project_training-80x80.jpg";s:5:"width";i:80;s:6:"height";i:80;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:14:"responsive-100";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:35:"6month_project_training-100x100.jpg";s:5:"width";i:100;s:6:"height";i:100;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:14:"responsive-150";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:35:"6month_project_training-150x150.jpg";s:5:"width";i:150;s:6:"height";i:150;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:19:"badgeos-achievement";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:35:"6month_project_training-100x100.jpg";s:5:"width";i:100;s:6:"height";i:100;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:20:"sow-carousel-default";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:35:"6month_project_training-200x182.jpg";s:5:"width";i:200;s:6:"height";i:182;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}}s:10:"image_meta";a:11:{s:8:"aperture";i:0;s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";i:0;s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";i:0;s:3:"iso";i:0;s:13:"shutter_speed";i:0;s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:11:"orientation";i:0;}}';


$unserialize_me=unserialize($s2mebership_details);

echo $unserialize_me['file'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not all under the first array:

```
$unserialize_me['file'];
$unserialize_me['sizes']['thumbnail']['file'];
$unserialize_me['sizes']['responsive-100']['file'];
$unserialize_me['sizes']['responsive-150']['file'];
$unserialize_me['sizes']['badgeos-achievement']['file'];
$unserialize_me['sizes']['sow-carousel-default']['file'];
```

if you do:

```
print '<pre>';
print_r($unserialize_me);
```

You can see all the values.

Edit:

if you want to change it while in the array, for example:

```
$unserialize_me['sizes']['thumbnail']['file'] = 'my/file/location/filename.jpg';
```

print_r again to see the change

Comment: Well that was awesome . But how to i replace the value . That's what i wanted to do at the very first place ? I have checked this and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

`$unserialize_me` is multidimensional array, original filename is in `$unserialize_me['file']`, others are under `sizes` key.

```
$filenames = array();
$filenames[] = $unserialize_me['file']; // original filename
foreach ($unserialize_me['sizes'] as $file) {
    $filenames[] = $file['file'];       // thumbnails
}

print_r($filenames);

/*
    Array
    (
        [0] => 6month_project_training.jpg
        [1] => 6month_project_training-80x80.jpg
        [2] => 6month_project_training-100x100.jpg
        [3] => 6month_project_training-150x150.jpg
        [4] => 6month_project_training-100x100.jpg
        [5] => 6month_project_training-200x182.jpg
    )
*/
```

If you need keys,

```
$filenames = array();
$filenames['orig'] = $unserialize_me['file'];
foreach ($unserialize_me['sizes'] as $key => $file) {
    $filenames[$key] = $file['file'];
}

print_r($filenames);

/*
    Array
    (
        [orig] => 6month_project_training.jpg
        [thumbnail] => 6month_project_training-80x80.jpg
        [responsive-100] => 6month_project_training-100x100.jpg
        [responsive-150] => 6month_project_training-150x150.jpg
        [badgeos-achievement] => 6month_project_training-100x100.jpg
        [sow-carousel-default] => 6month_project_training-200x182.jpg
    )
*/
```